# Sandbox IronPython?

Tags: .net, ironpython, appdomain, sandbox

Is it possible to run an IronPython interpreter inside my .Net application, but inside a sandbox?  I want to deny the IP script access to the filesystem while still allowing the app itself access.

Would this involve running the scripting engine in a second AppDomain?  How would I handcuff it so it can't do whatever it pleases?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's an article explaining how to [create an AppDomain and execute code in a sandbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763046.aspx). Just create the AppDomain and handcuff the code that runs inside it.

Comment: Oh.  Duh.  I was so bent on doing an IronPython-specific solution that it never occurred to me to search for a general solution.  I are dumb.

Comment: You are not dumb, you are learning, I wish more people were learning... anyway your question related to a problem I had so by asking here, you have not just helped yourself but me as well and probably others, thank you :)